# Generate Sequential Application number

Tags: salesforce

I have a requirement where I need to generate Unique Application Number and in sequential format.
Sample Application Number - APP-Date-0001 the 001 will keep on increasing for entire day and counter should be reset next day. So for next day it should again start from 001 with current date.
The problem will occur when 2 users are creating application at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Keep counter and last date it was used in custom setting or similar object.
But access that custom setting with normal SOQL, not via the special custom setting methods like getInstance().
Finally - in that SOQL query use FOR UPDATE. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_for_update.htm

If 2 operations start on same time - 1 will be held until other one finishes or timeout happens